# incompatible types when assigning memory in struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I making a program and no know why `Code::Blocks` show me some error:

```
error: conflicting types for 'loadSavedGame'
note: previous declaration of 'loadSavedGame' was here(In headers of file)
In function 'loadSavedGame':error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct saveGame' from type 'struct saveGame *'
```

and I do not understand because show me an error, if i have anothers functions declared in the same way, look:

```
        struct configParam{
           char *clave;
           char *valor;
        };

        struct saveGame{
           char *id;
           char *score;
           char *position;
           char *maze_level;
           char *achievements;
           char *time_playing;
           char *virtual_players;
        };

        void loadSettings(char fileName[],struct configParam *paramsReaded[], int *length, int *statusCode);
        void saveSettings(char fileName[],struct configParam paramsToWrite[], int length, int *statusCode);

        void loadSavedGame(char fileName[],struct saveGame *savedGamesReaded[], int *length, int *statusCode);
        void saveGame(char fileName[],struct saveGame savedGamesToWrite[], int length, int *statusCode);

    void loadSettings(char fileName[],struct configParam *paramsReaded[], int *length, int *statusCode){


        *paramsReaded = (struct configParam*)malloc((*length)*sizeof(struct configParam)); //THIS WORK
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<*length; j++){
            (*paramsReaded)[j].clave = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char)); //reserva de memoria para los miembros "clave" y "valor" de la estructura
            (*paramsReaded)[j].valor = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
        }

    }

void loadSavedGame(char fileName[], struct saveGame *savedGamesReaded, int *length, int *statusCode){

    *savedGamesReaded = (struct saveGame*)malloc((*length)*sizeof(struct saveGame)); // HERE SHOW AN ERROR :(
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<*length; j++){
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].id = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char)); 
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].score = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].position = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].maze_level = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].achievements = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].time_playing = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].virtual_players = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
    }






}
```

both functions work basically the same, only " loadsaveGame " points to a longer array, then I do not know why it does not work(function loadsaveGame)
thanks for your replies guys

Comment: Compiling the posted code, with all warnings enabled (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) causes the compiler to raise Not 2 but 19 errors and warnings.

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() and family of functions.  Because the type of the returned value is a `void *` so can be assigned to any pointer and adding such a cast will create problems when code maintenance is performed..   The expression `sizeof( char )`  is defined in the standard as 1  Multiplying by 1 has absolutely no effect on the value passed to malloc() and only results in cluttering the code

Comment: Please indent the code consistently.

Comment: this line: `*savedGamesReaded = malloc((*length)*sizeof(struct saveGame));` only updates the pointer on the call stack because the passed parameter is not correctly defined.  to update the original pointer, the passed in parameter needs to be `**`.

Comment: the savegame() function has the same name as the tag name of a struct definition.   This can/will create problems.   suggest using unique names

Answer (score 2):

Lets reduce this further to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

```
void loadSettings(struct configParam *paramsReaded[]){
    *paramsReaded = malloc(42); // This compiles.
}

void loadSavedGame(struct saveGame *savedGamesReaded){
    *savedGamesReaded = malloc(42); // This doesn't.
}
```

What's the difference? Lets investigate further by stripping the parameter identifiers and bodies to form prototypes for these two functions:

```
void loadSettings(struct configParam *[]);
void loadSavedGame(struct saveGame *);
```

Do you see the difference, now? The first one uses two levels of indirection (the `*` and the `[]`), while the second one only uses one level of indirection.

The first one uses a correct idiom, if you intend to assign to an object that exists after `loadSettings` returns. It looks sane.

The second one attempts to use that same pattern, but it's missing the `[]`... Hmmmm?

P.S. For future reference, please learn how to produce [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s so you can spot these kinds of simple typographical issues more easily by yourself.

P.P.S. Don't forget to check the return value of `malloc` (for `NULL` values) *before* you try to store something into the object it points to.

Comment: I had forgotten "[]", now its work, thank you for the explication Seb

Answer (score 0):

Error you get

> error: conflicting types for 'loadSavedGame'
>
> note: previous declaration of 'loadSavedGame' was here(In headers of file)

Is because this is prototype of function `loadSavedGame` -

```
void loadSavedGame(char fileName[],struct saveGame *savedGamesReaded[], int *length, int *statusCode);
```

And while defining you wrote-

```
void loadSavedGame(char fileName[], struct saveGame *savedGamesReaded, int *length, int *statusCode){
```

See type of parameter two in both

**1.** in first `struct saveGame *savedGamesReaded[]` (array of pointers to struct)

**2.** in second while defining function `struct saveGame *savedGamesReaded` (pointer to struct)

Thus types conflict , and the error. You miss there `[]` while defining function.

And next error is due to this -

```
 *savedGamesReaded = (struct saveGame*)malloc((*length)*sizeof(struct saveGame)); // HERE SHOW AN ERROR :(
```

This also due to above problem. If you keep the array of pointer i.e `struct saveGame *savedGamedReaded[]` this will be a valid statement and won't produce error. As `*` and `[]` will provide two levels of indirection.

But if not then using `*` will create problem. Then you will have to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

the following code may be more of what you are looking to implement

The code needs to have the error checking for each of the malloc's added

All the 'clutter' is removed from the code.
All the unused function parameters are removed from the code
The code compiles with no errors/warnings

```
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_STRING (100)

struct configParam
{
   char *clave;
   char *valor;
};

struct saveGame
{
   char *id;
   char *score;
   char *position;
   char *maze_level;
   char *achievements;
   char *time_playing;
   char *virtual_players;
};

//prototypes
void loadSavedGame(struct saveGame **savedGamesReaded, int *length );
void loadSettings( struct configParam **paramsReaded, int *length );

void loadSettings( struct configParam **paramsReaded, int *length )
{
    *paramsReaded = malloc((*length)*sizeof(struct configParam)); //THIS WORK
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<*length; j++)
    {
        (*paramsReaded)[j].clave = malloc(MAX_STRING); //reserva de memoria para los miembros "clave" y "valor" de la estructura
        (*paramsReaded)[j].valor = malloc(MAX_STRING);
    }

}

void loadSavedGame(struct saveGame **savedGamesReaded, int *length )
{
    *savedGamesReaded = malloc((*length)*sizeof(struct saveGame));
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<*length; j++)
    {
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].id              = malloc(MAX_STRING);
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].score           = malloc(MAX_STRING);
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].position        = malloc(MAX_STRING);
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].maze_level      = malloc(MAX_STRING);
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].achievements    = malloc(MAX_STRING);
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].time_playing    = malloc(MAX_STRING);
        (*savedGamesReaded)[j].virtual_players = malloc(MAX_STRING);
    }
} // end function: loadSavedGame
```